# how to run impress inside backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, impress.js

I have read some code of strut.io but still confusing.
Here is the problem I got, I want to load impress().init();
when

```
 <script type="text/template" id="impress-demo-template">
    <div  id="impress"  onReady=" impress().init();">

    </div>
</script>`
```

this is ready. And i got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null 
I know this function needs to load after all children in div#impress.
So I want to know how to deal with it. Should I add that function in my backbone view?
https://github.com/lostpupil/final_project_impressjs/
here is my github repo for that code, so I store data in Avos Cloud and this funciton is tested by test.html and demo.js.

Answer (score 0):

well it seems nobody knows this question, and finally i wrote that program
the program is now host on http://breakingbad.vipsinaapp.com/ and the source code is host on [github](https://github.com/lostpupil/final_project_impressjs)
feel free to make feed back, help me to improve, I am new to backbonejs, so I will thank you for kindness help.